# Rails 4 - writing a route with concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, routes

I'm trying to figure out how to write a route using the concerns function.

Section 2.8 of the Rails guide sets out an example of how to do this, as:

```
resources :messages, concerns: :commentable
```

I have models for Project and Potential Uses. The associations are:

Project

```
belongs_to :profile
has_many :potential_uses
```

Potential Uses

```
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :user
```

I have a view partial in my projects folder, with:

```
<%= link_to 'Add a potential use', new__potential_use_path(@project) %>
```

In my routes file, I am trying to figure out how to link project with potential use so that the new potential use path is associated with the project. I think I need concerns for this because user also has potential uses, so the route to potential use cannot be nested inside project.

I am trying:

```
    resources :projects do
    concerns: :potential_uses, 
    member do

      put "publish" => "projects#publish", as: :publish 
      put "remove" => "projects#remove", as: :remove 
      put "approve" => "projects/approve", as: :approve
      put "closed" => "projects/closed", as: :closed

    end
    resource :favourite, module: :projects
  end
```

I can't start the server while the routes are expressed like this. An error message says:

```
routes.rb:137: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    concerns: :potential_uses,
```

The rails guide does not show the example of using concerns as needing additional end statements. Can anyone see what I've done wrong here?

Comment: I would guess that the problem is you're mixing your hash-styles: `put "publish" => "projects#publish", as: :publish ` you have a hash-rocket *and* the `:` style of hash... convert to one or the other and try it?

Comment: @TarynEast - the line that has the problem is "concerns: :potential_uses,". I don't know how to do the conversion you're describing on the following lines. Can you show me an example of what you mean that I should change?

Comment: either use hash-rocket style hash eg: `put "publish" => "projects#publish", :as => :publish ` OR use `:` style hash eg: `put publish: "projects#publish", as: :publish ` You rproblem is that the `publish` part has a hashrocket, and the `as` part uses `:` and you can't mix like that